# How do I write a batch script to search for a specific file based on folder name?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to write a batch script that searches for occurrences of a file named `SQLite.Interop.dll` in a certain directory. There will actually be many occurrences of this file nested under different subdirectories, and specifically I'd like it to find the one where the folder name is `net45`.

I started to try and write a batch script myself by piecing together different StackOverflow answers, but ultimately didn't get very far. Here's my initial, feeble attempt:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /r C:\Specified\Directory %%i in (SQLite.Interop.dll) do (set str = %%i & if x%str:net45=%==x%filestr% (copy %%i ./SQLite.Interop.dll & goto BreakStmt)

:BreakStmt
endlocal
```

Things not yet working:

- The Specified Directory path on the `for /r` statement
- Substring searching for `net45` in the file path
- Not sure if `&` is the proper way to chain commands?
- General syntax... I'm a bit like a fish out of water with this batch stuff...

Comment: Use FOR /R /D to find the directory first. Then use an IF EXIST.

Comment: @Squashman that might not work though, because a subfolder might have "net45" in the directory name, but not contain the file.

Comment: Can you please clarify: do you want to find the `*.dll` file where `net45` is _any_ part of the path, or where it is the _immediate_ parent directory? could there be multiple matches? what exactly do you want to do if you found the file(s)?

Comment: @aschipfl yes it's a pretty flexible search that I'm after: the net45 can indeed be any part of the path (need not be the immediate parent) and there could indeed be multiple matches (in which case just use the first one).

Comment: So you need to define what the "first one" is: is there a specific sort order, or is it just random?

Comment: Just random, whichever one you encounter first (in any order) works

Comment: @SoaperGEM that is why I said to use an IF EXIST to test for the file when it finds the dirrctory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursive `dir /s` and filter the output by the directory name surrounded by `\`, parse the result with `for /f`:

```c
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /s /b "C:\Specified\Directory\SQLite.Interop.dll" ^| find /i "\net45\"
') do copy /y "%%a" .
```

This method doesn't require delayed variable expansion.

Comment: I'm getting "File Not Found" from this. One example of where the file lives is in `C:\Specified\Directory\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.98.1\build\net45\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll` ... does that help explain it a little better?

Comment: Run `dir /s /b "C:\Specified\Directory\SQLite.Interop.dll"` from the Command Prompt console to check you're typing it correctly.

Comment: Yes of course. And you're right -- I had typo'ed it the first time. This works perfectly. Thank you!